# Fill fields in object, from other object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In Javascript (ES6) have two objects with data.

```
const template = {
    a: '',
    b: '',
    x: ''
}
```

This is the data object I will receive

```
const data = {
    a: 'test',
    b: 'test',
    c: 'test'
}
```

How can I map the data from my received object to my template object **without allowing values that are not present in the template object.**

So the result should be this.

```
const result = {
    a: 'test',
    b: 'test',
    x: ''
}
```

Comment: what happens to a property which is in `template`, but not in `data`?

Comment: Ah good question! It stays, let me change the code to reflect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could get the `template` object and the properties with the same keys from `data`.

```js
const
    template = { a: '', b: '', x: '' },
    data = { a: 'test', b: 'test', c: 'test' },
    result = Object.assign(
        {},
        template,
        ...Object.keys(template).map(k => k in data && { [k]: data[k] })
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use a [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop :

```js
const template = {
  a: '',
  b: ''
}

const data = {
  a: 'test',
  b: 'test',
  c: 'test'
}

const result = {};

for (let k in template) {
  result[k] = data[k];
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```js
 let result = {};
 const template = {
      a: '',
      b: ''
 }
 const data = {
     a: 'test',
     b: 'test',
     c: 'test'
 }

 for (let prop in data) {
    if(prop in template) result[prop] = data[prop];
 }

 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun you could use some Proxy magic :)

```js
const template = {
  a: '',
  b: ''
}

const data = {
  a: 'test',
  b: 'test',
  c: 'test'
}

const result = { ...new Proxy(data, {
    ownKeys: () => Object.keys(template)
  })
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Proxy is new to me! Thanks for the 'fun' option, I'll check the docs

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop on the keys of your template, and set the value with the data object with the same key.

```js
const data = {
    a: 'test',
    b: 'test',
    c: 'test'
}

const template = {
    a: '',
    b: ''
}

Object.keys(template).forEach((key) => template[key] = data[key])

console.log(template)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use of `Array.reduce` to look at your object and only change the keys you are interested in. This method will also handle the case where the key you want to copy from `data` is not here. Also we have created a new object, we do not mutate the existing one.

---

**Without mutation *(new object)***

```js
const template = {
  a: '',
  b: '',
};

const data = {
  a: 'test',
  b: 'test',
  c: 'test',
};

const ret = Object.keys(template).reduce((tmp, x) => {
  tmp[x] = data[x] !== void 0 ? data[x] : tmp[x];

  return tmp;
}, {
  ...template,
});

console.log(ret);
```

---

**Mutating the object *(use the old object)***

```js
const template = {
  a: '',
  b: '',
};

const data = {
  a: 'test',
  b: 'test',
  c: 'test',
};

Object.keys(template).forEach((x) => {
  template[x] = data[x] !== void 0 ? data[x] : template[x];
});

console.log(template);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const template = {
  a: '',
  b: ''
}

const data = {
  a: 'test',
  b: 'test',
  c: 'test'
}

function setData(inputTemplate, inputData) {
    outputObject = {}
    for (var key in inputTemplate) {
        if (inputData[key]) {
          outputObject[key] = inputData[key];
        }
    }
    return outputObject
}

console.log(setData(template, data))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use **reduce**

Example :

```js
const template = {
  a: '',
  b: ''
}

const data = {
  a: 'test',
  b: 'test',
  c: 'test'
}

const res = Object.keys(template).reduce((all, acc) => {
  all[acc] = data[acc]
  return all
}, {})

console.log(res)
```