# How to iterate over two objects and update one's values based on the other in JS?

Tags: javascript

How can I get this object's values populated, if its keys match the second object's keys?

**Object to be populated**

```
const task = {
      name: '',
      description: '',
      status: '',
      priority: '',
      due_date: '',
      due_date_time: '',
      parent: '',
      time_estimate: '',
      start_date: '',
      start_date_time: '',
      assignees: {},
      archived: ''
  }
```

**Original Object**

```
const taskData = { 
  id: '476ky1',
  custom_id: null,
  name: 'Reunião com o novo Gerente de Vendas - Airton',
  text_content: null,
  description: null,
  status: 
   { id: 'p3203621_11svBhbO',
     status: 'to do',
     color: '#d3d3d3',
     orderindex: 0,
     type: 'open' },
  orderindex: '1.16183176837360000000000000000000',
  date_created: '1618317683783',
  date_updated: '1618317683783',
  date_closed: null,
  archived: false,
  creator: 
   { id: 3184709,
     username: 'Michael Jackson',
     color: '#455963',
     email: 'email@gmail.com',
     profilePicture: null },
  assignees: 
   [ { id: 3184709,
       username: 'Antonio Santos',
       color: '#455963',
       initials: 'AS',
       email: 'santosonit@gmail.com',
       profilePicture: null } ],
  watchers: 
   [ { id: 3184709,
       username: 'Antonio Santos',
       color: '#455963',
       initials: 'AS',
       email: 'santosonit@gmail.com',
       profilePicture: null } ],
  checklists: [],
  tags: [],
  parent: null,
  priority: null,
  due_date: null,
  start_date: null,
  points: null,
  time_estimate: null,
  time_spent: 0,
  custom_fields: [],
  dependencies: [],
  linked_tasks: [],
  team_id: '3101702',
  url: 'https://app.clickup.com/t/476ky1',
  permission_level: 'create',
  list: { id: '13700791', name: 'List', access: true },
  project: { id: '7328469', name: 'hidden', hidden: true, access: true },
  folder: { id: '7328469', name: 'hidden', hidden: true, access: true },
  space: { id: '3203621' },
  attachments: [] 
}
```

Now, don't condemn me yet, as I'm just starting to deal with objects and I'm sure that there are many ways to do it, but is `for loop` an approach to look at? It doesn't modify `task` object, right. So how would I go about returning `task` populated?

```
for(let a = 0; a < task.length; a++){
  for (let n = 0; n < data.length; a++){
    if(Object.keys(task) == Object.keys(data)){
      Object.values(task) = Object.values(data)
    }
  }
}
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fill fields in object, from other object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55103138/fill-fields-in-object-from-other-object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've already got the keys you want nicely defined in `task`, so we can simply loop through them using `for (let k in task)`. If `taskData[k]` doesn't have a value this solution reverts to using an empty string. (Scroll to the bottom of the code block to see the solution!)

```js
const taskData = { 
  id: '476ky1',
  custom_id: null,
  name: 'Reunião com o novo Gerente de Vendas - Airton',
  text_content: null,
  description: null,
  status: 
   { id: 'p3203621_11svBhbO',
     status: 'to do',
     color: '#d3d3d3',
     orderindex: 0,
     type: 'open' },
  orderindex: '1.16183176837360000000000000000000',
  date_created: '1618317683783',
  date_updated: '1618317683783',
  date_closed: null,
  archived: false,
  creator: 
   { id: 3184709,
     username: 'Michael Jackson',
     color: '#455963',
     email: 'email@gmail.com',
     profilePicture: null },
  assignees: 
   [ { id: 3184709,
       username: 'Antonio Santos',
       color: '#455963',
       initials: 'AS',
       email: 'santosonit@gmail.com',
       profilePicture: null } ],
  watchers: 
   [ { id: 3184709,
       username: 'Antonio Santos',
       color: '#455963',
       initials: 'AS',
       email: 'santosonit@gmail.com',
       profilePicture: null } ],
  checklists: [],
  tags: [],
  parent: null,
  priority: null,
  due_date: null,
  start_date: null,
  points: null,
  time_estimate: null,
  time_spent: 0,
  custom_fields: [],
  dependencies: [],
  linked_tasks: [],
  team_id: '3101702',
  url: 'https://app.clickup.com/t/476ky1',
  permission_level: 'create',
  list: { id: '13700791', name: 'List', access: true },
  project: { id: '7328469', name: 'hidden', hidden: true, access: true },
  folder: { id: '7328469', name: 'hidden', hidden: true, access: true },
  space: { id: '3203621' },
  attachments: [] 
};

const task = {
    name: '',
    description: '',
    status: '',
    priority: '',
    due_date: '',
    due_date_time: '',
    parent: '',
    time_estimate: '',
    start_date: '',
    start_date_time: '',
    assignees: {},
    archived: ''
};

// Here's the solution!
for (let k in task) task[k] = taskData[k] ?? '';

console.log({ task });
```

Note that if you're sure `taskData` contains a superset of the keys in `task`, you can simply use:

```
for (let k in task) task[k] = taskData[k];
```

Answer (score 5):

If all the keys in `task` exist in `taskData`, you can just iterate the keys using `forEach` to copy the data:

```js
Object.keys(task).forEach(k => task[k] = taskData[k])
```

**Note**

This will copy *references* to anything in `taskData` which is not a primitive, so that if you modify one of them in `task` it will also change the value in `taskData`. If this is not desired behaviour, you should make a deep copy using one of the methods described in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript).

```js
const task = {
      name: '',
      description: '',
      status: '',
      priority: '',
      due_date: '',
      due_date_time: '',
      parent: '',
      time_estimate: '',
      start_date: '',
      start_date_time: '',
      assignees: {},
      archived: ''
  }
  
const taskData = { 
  id: '476ky1',
  custom_id: null,
  name: 'Reunião com o novo Gerente de Vendas - Airton',
  text_content: null,
  description: null,
  status: 
   { id: 'p3203621_11svBhbO',
     status: 'to do',
     color: '#d3d3d3',
     orderindex: 0,
     type: 'open' },
  orderindex: '1.16183176837360000000000000000000',
  date_created: '1618317683783',
  date_updated: '1618317683783',
  date_closed: null,
  archived: false,
  creator: 
   { id: 3184709,
     username: 'Michael Jackson',
     color: '#455963',
     email: 'email@gmail.com',
     profilePicture: null },
  assignees: 
   [ { id: 3184709,
       username: 'Antonio Santos',
       color: '#455963',
       initials: 'AS',
       email: 'santosonit@gmail.com',
       profilePicture: null } ],
  watchers: 
   [ { id: 3184709,
       username: 'Antonio Santos',
       color: '#455963',
       initials: 'AS',
       email: 'santosonit@gmail.com',
       profilePicture: null } ],
  checklists: [],
  tags: [],
  parent: null,
  priority: null,
  due_date: null,
  start_date: null,
  points: null,
  time_estimate: null,
  time_spent: 0,
  custom_fields: [],
  dependencies: [],
  linked_tasks: [],
  team_id: '3101702',
  url: 'https://app.clickup.com/t/476ky1',
  permission_level: 'create',
  list: { id: '13700791', name: 'List', access: true },
  project: { id: '7328469', name: 'hidden', hidden: true, access: true },
  folder: { id: '7328469', name: 'hidden', hidden: true, access: true },
  space: { id: '3203621' },
  attachments: [] 
}

Object.keys(task).forEach(k => task[k] = taskData[k])

console.log(task)
```

Comment: This assigns the reference of anything that is not a primitive value. I'm not sure if OP wants this.

Comment: @Christopher thanks, I've made a note about that in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to approach this task is to filter the original object by some *allowed* keys.

```js
const taskData={id:"476ky1",custom_id:null,name:"Reuni\xe3o com o novo Gerente de Vendas - Airton",text_content:null,description:null,status:{id:"p3203621_11svBhbO",status:"todo",color:"#d3d3d3",orderindex:0,type:"open"},orderindex:"1.16183176837360000000000000000000",date_created:"1618317683783",date_updated:"1618317683783",date_closed:null,archived:!1,creator:{id:3184709,username:"Michael Jackson",color:"#455963",email:"email@gmail.com",profilePicture:null},assignees:[{id:3184709,username:"Antonio Santos",color:"#455963",initials:"AS",email:"santosonit@gmail.com",profilePicture:null}],watchers:[{id:3184709,username:"Antonio Santos",color:"#455963",initials:"AS",email:"santosonit@gmail.com",profilePicture:null}],checklists:[],tags:[],parent:null,priority:null,due_date:null,start_date:null,points:null,time_estimate:null,time_spent:0,custom_fields:[],dependencies:[],linked_tasks:[],team_id:"3101702",url:"https://app.clickup.com/t/476ky1",permission_level:"create",list:{id:"13700791",name:"List",access:!0},project:{id:"7328469",name:"hidden",hidden:!0,access:!0},folder:{id:"7328469",name:"hidden",hidden:!0,access:!0},space:{id:"3203621"},attachments:[]};

const allowedKeys = ['name', 'description', 'status']; // etc. Add all the keys you want to keep here

const filtered = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(taskData).filter(
    ([key, val]) => allowedKeys.includes(key)
  )
);

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure this is filtering the object in its entirety, though

Comment: Just add all the keys you want to keep to the `allowedKeys` array.

Comment: Felt like deleting my comment for its/my stupidity. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I was too lazy to add all of the keys.